# Nexus 4 v4.3 Facebook connect

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm trying to develop a application integrate with Facebook connect, it work fine on other device (Note 2 v4.1.2) but same code unable to login to Facebook on Nexus 4 v4.3.

Is it a bug? is there a known issue regarding this?

Following is log shown by facebook sdk

```
10-05 10:59:29.864: D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(7727): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=623266737691185&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D623266737691185%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied&display=touch&_rdr
```

Thanks

Comment: open facebook login dialog through

`<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Connect used OAuth as authentication method, and part of OAuth param include timestamp. If the time of the device is not correctly set, it will produce incorrect timestamp and result in the error above.

Hope Facebook can be more clear about their error message.